# Split big file where lines are separated by semicolon and split parts can contain semicolon inside quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split lines into parts in a big file (200MB-5GB) where lines looks like this

value1;value2;"value3;extra";value4;"value5;extra"

Line needs to be split by semicolon . Regular `String.Split` does not work since semicolons can be inside of the quotes.

I think regular expression would work best here especially if file has millions of lines. I appreciate any guidance or code that would help me to split.

Update:

The result I want to see for the above sample line is

```
value1
value2
"value3;extra"
value4
"value5;extra"
```

Thank you

Comment: string.split will work, I guess that it will just not follow all your expectations. Please provide an example of how do you want the output line to look like. Also, you may want to use the term "semicolon" instead of "semi column".

Comment: Are you able to process this file line-by-line, or will it be presented as chunks of data?

Comment: can you remove the "'s  before the split on ;?

Comment: @AdrianWragg I have the whole file available

Comment: @Yoztastic quotes are part of the value that I need to retain

Comment: @BartoszKP I added sample result that I want to get after splitting one line

Comment: @m.buettner This is not the same as CSV, please reconsider your downvote

Comment: CSV files, contrary to the name, are not always comma-separated. Basically CSV is an umbrella term for all files where there are records in separate lines, with fields separated by some delimiter. Try using something like [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) to parse the lines.

Comment: I would recommend KBCSV data reader, which can solve the job easily and can handle the varios problems with enquoted data.

Comment: Parse it as a CSV file. The `TextFieldParser` class recommend in the answer is the way to go.

Comment: "I think regular expression would work best here especially if file has millions of lines." That's the slowest approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Tim thanks for the comment, would regex improve performance when matching against the whole file and not just one line?

Comment: @AlexS: That makes no difference, also, i don't see the need for regex here.

Comment: @AlexS as the others pointed out, this is very well CSV. and I never downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and use the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(var input = File.OpenRead("input.txt"))
        using(var tfp = new TextFieldParser(input))
        {
            tfp.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });
            tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            var fields = tfp.ReadFields();
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(field);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. [TextFieldParser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your asnwer

Comment: Note to admins: I did not expect to get this answer with so many downvotes :)

Comment: @AlexS: Note that your sample data suggests that you are using a quoting character `"`. Therefore set `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true`. Also, use the `using` statement(edited Alex answer accordingly). Btw, Stackoverflow is moderated by it's users (with enough reputation).